# How to disassemble VBX files?

Tags: disassembly

I have a 16 bit VBX file for Visual Basic 3 which I'd like to disassembly. Which program can analyze it?

I tried IDA Free, but it seems only OCX are supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only tool I'm aware of that can handle VB3 stuff is [Dodi's Visual Basic 3/4 Decompiler](http://vbdis4.angelfire.com/). You might also look at this basically identical [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983709/vb3-decompiler).

Answer (score 2):

VBX files are standard NE (New Executable) files which use a few special entrypoints and structures used by VB. IDA Free does not support NE file format, you need  to use the full version (at least Starter) or another disassembler .You can find the details of the VBX API in the VB Control Development Kit (CDK) shipped with [Visual Basic Pro 3.0](https://winworldpc.com/download/4DA81FE7-57D8-11E4-A90F-7054D21A8599) or by searching for "vbapi.h". Some additional information is available [in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa268983)