# How can I extract resource images from Visual Basic 6 Malware

Tags: malware, visual-basic, pe-resources

I am reverse engineering some malware that is written in VB6. I found this tool which tried to decompile the .exe, but I noticed that the image that is being loaded by the .exe is suspicious and I want to extract it for further analysis.

Someone mentioned resource extractor would work, but that only pulls the ICON from the file, not the image below.

**Is there a technique or tool that will extract this image?**

[image: Image that I want to extract]
Here is some somewhat related topics that have brought me thus far.

[How to disassemble VBX files?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4077/how-to-disassemble-vbx-files)

Comment: If this tool provides any info about the offset(there are some that looks like that in the bottom two) at which this "image" is located you can just write a simple script that will copy bytes from that offset and save them into a separate file.

Comment: Yeah I might have to do that. I would like to avoid it though . I dint think this tool tells this information though. The pro edition of this tool allows swapping of images so maybe I can swap images and the do a bindiff... Just thinking though.

Comment: I would say this way is preferred. You don't know what kind of processing the tool might do when extracting the bitmap.

Comment: I just need to find the image point if it is an image or posing as one

Comment: Found this on the web Maybe it will work: http://www.sandsprite.com/blogs/index.php?uid=7%26pid=57

Comment: it's a common practice to hide some code this way only xor'ed with a key.

Comment: Thank you everyone . I will try the following from @John

Comment: Which tool is this?

Comment: I think under normal circumstances John's tool would have worked. I ended up using some online tool image from binary extrator tool

Comment: What is tool is this?